# Contribution page in a loop?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, relationships

I have a contribution page set up that I'm sending users to using a link from a webform, which includes the cid and checksum so that the contribution page is prefilled with the user's data.

when the user submits the page, having selected the relevant payment options, the page is simply re-presented to them rather than taking them off to the payment processor, Paypal standard in this instance.

If I use the page as a logged in user, it works without a problem.

Running D7 and Civi 4.6.10 currently, although about to update to current 4.6.x. Is this a known issue?

Looking at Firebug, I can see that in the case where the user is not logged in, I'm seeing a 404 on a JS file (/sites/default/files/js/jquery.min.map;) which I don't get when logged in.

I'm thinking this may be theme-related?

Any ideas on how to debug or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was caused by the fact that there was no 'user 0' record in the Drupal database. Reinstating that, the problem was resolved.